# How is unit testing is done in Spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, junit

Simple question looking for simple answer
If I have a given class and a method I want to test what would be the procedure for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` along with JUnit to test all the functionality related to dao and service layer.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) contains everything you need about the mock objects and mock injection capabilities. They did a great job with it.

Typically, you will be doing this sort of thing (adding a bit to the example from the documentation):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/META-INF/spring/testContext.xml")
public class XmlApplicationContextTests {
    // class body...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, download spirnt-test.jar or configure your pom.xml

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml")


public class CategoryServiceTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Resource
    private CategoryService categoryService;


    @Ignore@Rollback(false)
    public void testSave() {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("chicken");
        category.setCreatedTime(new java.util.Date());
        categoryService.save(category);

    }

}
```

It is better to extends from **AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests**, because it  use spring transaction, and rollback  can be turn off by adding **@Rollback(false)** before the test case.